# Why Would a QTP object class change from JavaWindow to Window

Tags: java, qtp, regression-testing

I have an existing set of QTP regression tests that I wrote and have executed through several regression test cycles successfully. I have a JavaWindow that contains several JavaTables where I parse the table data into an array and verify it against the expected results in Excel spreadsheets.

In the current test cycle, the JavaWindow (which contained the JavaTables that I could read and verify) has now changed to a class of Window, and QTP sees this Window as simply one object. I can no longer verify the table data inside the window.

What may have happened that could cause the QTP class of the JavaWindow to change to a class of Window? No code changes have been made to this window, and I have verified that the Java versions on both my test box and app server have not changed and are valid for the current version of QTP.

Any insight into this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the Java addin in QTP isn't working. There can be several causes for this.

- QTP was loaded without selecting the Java addin in the addin manager
- The test's Record and Run settings don't include your application
- The Java application was opened before QTP (so QTP wasn't able to hook this application)

Answer (score 0):

Along with the other answer, it might also happen, when you mess up your with Environment Variables. Lets say you installed `StarTeam` (it happened to me) recently which updates some of the existing environment variables set by QTP like `JAVA_OPTIONS`.

If it was working before & you could not figure out the issue, i would suggest you to repair UFT (using control panel options).